# Extending VS 2010: to include additional items on Right Click context menu (add) on solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, extensibility

I wish to create an additional item on the context sensitive right click "ADD" on the solution explorer in vs 2010.

Basically it currently looks like this

```
New Item
Existing Item
New Folder
Add ASP.NET FOLDER // ACTUALLY THIS IS A MENU with a SUB MENU
Class
```

What i am trying to do is create a new item similar to "Add asp.net folder" hence it will have subitems

Basically it will be something like this

```
Add JS items
     Add new model
     Add new plugin
```

Basically clicking on "add new model" or "add new plugin" will create a new file UTF-8 and include in the project. It will contain some default code.

I am having a real issue trying to find a good example of how to do this.

Any ideas where i should look?

Anybody seen anything similar?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here are some docs to point you in the right direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165473.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164699.aspx

Basically commands and menus work the same throughout all of VS, one tricky part is just finding the right Guid of the parent menu that you want to hook in to.